# passing boolean method execution to another class - java

Tags: java, class, methods, boolean

I have a boolean method

```
public boolean addCar(CarReg carReg, Car car){
    return ?;
}
```

This method above is meant to be passed to another class where the actual check occurs

```
public class Car{ 
    Map<CarReg, Car> carMap = new HashMap<carReg, Car>();
    //if the check is successfull, the details are added to the collection
    public boolean addCar(CarReg carReg, Car car){
        If (garage.getOwner().toString == "pete"){
            carMap.put(carReg, car);
            return true;
        }
    }
}
```

Can I call it by saying car.addCar(carReg, car);
Actually, I have tried that but it does not seem to work. Unless the error is somewhere else.

Comment: Can you be clearer about where everything is supposed to be?  I suspect the answer is to use `this`, but it's pretty unclear.

Comment: You can pass an object, you can pass the result of a method invocation, but you can't pass a method. Please explain what you want to achieve, at a higher level.

Comment: You should be using the `equals` method, not `==` for comparing strings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unlike with functional languages, in object-oriented languages like Java, you don't pass around functions, but rather you pass around objects on which you can call methods. There are a few ways you can get your boolean method visible to the Car class. I'm going to call the method `canAddCar` just to avoid confusion with `Car#addCar`.

The simplest is if you can define the method in the Car class itself:

```
public class Car {
  public boolean canAddCar(CarReg carReg, Car car) {
    // logic for checking if you can add the car
  }
  public boolean addCar(CarReg carReg, Car car) { 
    if (canAddCar(carReg, car)) {
      // logic for adding the car goes here
      return true;
    } else {
      // anything special if you can't add the car?
      return false;
    }
  }
}
```

The next simplest is if you can define the method in the class of an object that you're passing in, like `CarReg`

This makes sense, if it's the carReg's responsibility to check if you can add a car. Based on the naming, I would imagine you probably want the carReg to also be responsible for adding the car as well, but I'm not showing that here:

```
public class CarReg {
  public boolean canAddCar(Car car) {
    // logic for testing if you can add the car, for example:
    return (car.getOwner().toString().equals("pete"));
  }
}

public class Car {
  public boolean addCar(CarReg carReg, Car car) {
    if (carReg.canAddCar(car)) {
      // ...
    } else {
      // ...
    }
  }
}
```

Next, you can pass in another object to your class that can take responsibility for the check.
This can be another object to the method `addCar`, or a property of the `Car` class. I'm showing the latter in this example (since the previous example is basically the former):

```
// might as well use an interface if you'll have multiple methods of checking
public interface CarChecker {
  boolean canAddCar(CarReg carReg, Car car);
}

// specific implementation of the CarChecker interface
// you can instantiate this and pass it into the Car class via a setter
public class MyCarChecker implements CarChecker {
  public boolean canAddCar(CarReg carReg, Car car) {
    // checking logic goes here
  }
}

public class Car {
  private CarChecker carChecker;
  // you'll have to implent getCarChecker and setCarChecker 
  // (or let your IDE generate the getters and setters)

  // assuming you'll call setCarChecker somewhere (or have it wired up via IoC)

  public boolean addCar(CarReg carReg, Car car) {
    if (carChecker.canAddCar(carReg, car)) {
      // ...
    } else {
      // ...
    }
  }
}
```

There are several other ways (anonymous classes, singleton classes, static methods) but these are the most common and should get you started.